# .htaccess rewrite url with 2 elements to 1 elemnt

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL with 2 parameters `/manufacturer/product.html` and I need to redirect to the URL without "manufacturer", ie. `/product.html`

```
RewriteRule ^\/manufacturer\/(.*)$ \/$1 [L]
```

This does not work.

can you help me?

Comment: remove the front slash or make it optional `RewriteRule ^/?manufacturer/(.*)$ /$1 [L]`

Comment: @infomf let me know if my solution works for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that will work for you, make sure you paste this in your root .htaccess file. (rename the current .htaccess file to .htaccess.bak and paste the below code in a new .htaccess file in root directory)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^manufacturer/product\.html$ /product.html? [L,R]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` (permanent redirect).